# Loading media from specific directory to a path - android

Tags: android, media-player

I have created a directory in device storage by this command:

```
File zenglishSubDirectoryDownloadByLevel = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/zenglish/sounds/level_1");
                    if(!zenglishSubDirectoryDownloadByLevel.exists()){
                        zenglishSubDirectoryDownloadByLevel.mkdirs();
                    }
```

and this goes fine. now I would like to load musics just in `/zenglish/sounds/level_1` path with an adapter. so I have used this code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/zenglish/sounds/level_1");
Uri soundURI = Uri.fromFile(f);
Log.e("sound uri","=>"+soundURI.getPath());
String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
};
Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
       // MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // is ok
        soundURI, // is empty
        projection,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1",
        null,
        "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + ") ASC, " +
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + ") ASC, " +
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC"
);
if (cursor == null) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

So, my problem is that `soundURI` always is empty (cursor is null) but `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` works well and load all audio files in my device storage. How can I load musics from `/zenglish/sounds/level_1` to `soundURI`?

what is the correct path?

Comment: `mkdirs()`. That will return true or false. As it might fail you should check return value before continuing.

Comment: `soundURI, // is empty` What do you mean with an empty uri?

Comment: @greenapps I mean `cursor` is null

Comment: Then adapt your post to begin with.

Comment: is the media file present in that file?You can also use select_arg to get the song from a fixed file